# Как отследить появления блока div на сайте anti-captcha.com и подать звуковой сигнал

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

На сайте [Anti Captcha](http://anti-captcha.com) необходимо отслеживать начало обработки капчи. Сам сервис имеет монитор онлайн и в момент, когда начинается отгадывание капчи, генерируется блок div, в который выгружаются картинки с капчами. Вот нужно отслеживать этот момент и подавать звуковой сигнал..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11546242/3049150

Comment: @FeroxTL Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 1):

C помощью tamperMonkey для Chrome или GreaceMonkey для FireFox

1. Устанавливаем tamperMonkey
2. пишем скрипт для страницы где нужно отлавливать:

   ```
   // ==UserScript==
   // @name         My Fancy New Userscript
   // @namespace    http://your.homepage/
   // @version      0.1
   // @description  enter something useful
   // @author       You
   // @match        // полный адрес сайта на котором будет скрипт работать
   // @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
   // ==/UserScript==

   // сам скрипт

   timer = 1000; // 1 секунда
   function check() {
       var element = $('div.className');
       if(element.length) { // если елемент появился
           // тут подаем сигнал, как пример добавляем проигрывать в конец страницы с какой-то музыкой $(body).append(radio);
       }
       else {
           setTimeout(check, timer);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: а можно немного по подробней ?

Comment: @ROGG c помощью tamperMonkey можно отловить появление div и подать звуковой сигнал.

Comment: @ROGG добавил описание к ответу.